# R package gdalUtils does not work for hdf4 files

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal, hdf

when I load rgdal and GdalUtils packages to read hdf4 file, with the following

```
library(raster)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(proj4)
library(gdalUtils)`
```

it gives the following warning message

```
rgdal: version: 1.2-12, (SVN revision 681)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.0, released 2017/04/28
 Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/Geosoft/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/gdal
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/Geosoft/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/proj
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-5
```

Afterwards I tried the following

```
file<-"D:\\sample_lst\\MOD11A2.A2000089.h21v07.006.2015058064314.hdf"
sds<-get_subdatasets(file)
```

It begin extremely busy, just returns nothing

Even I have tried the following

```
library("gdalUtils")
gdal_setInstallation(verbose=TRUE)
getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")
```

but takes a lot of time scanning file pathes.

Is there anybody who can help me to read subdatasets and gdalinfo

Comment: Hi. Since you are on windows, you may try install GDAL from OSGEO4w. The path to OSGEO on windows is usually easily recognized by gdalUtils. This may help: http://lbusett.github.io/MODIStsp/articles/installation.html#windows-1

Comment: I wonder if the `gdal-config` utility is installed together with `rgdal`. If yes, `gdal-config --formats` could provide some insight.